# FPDF+FPDI autoprint

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I need to `import pdf` file into `fpdf` and `print it silently`. I use fpdi extension to load existing pdf, but I have no idea how to autoprint it.

This is how autoprint in fpdf works - 2 additional classes around fpdf (from their examples).

```
require('lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require('lib/fpdi-1.6.1/fpdi.php');


class PDF_JavaScript extends FPDF {

    protected $javascript;
    protected $n_js;

    function IncludeJS($script, $isUTF8=false) {
        if(!$isUTF8)
            $script=utf8_encode($script);
        $this->javascript=$script;
    }

    function _putjavascript() {
        $this->_newobj();
        $this->n_js=$this->n;
        $this->_put('<<');
        $this->_put('/Names [(EmbeddedJS) '.($this->n+1).' 0 R]');
        $this->_put('>>');
        $this->_put('endobj');
        $this->_newobj();
        $this->_put('<<');
        $this->_put('/S /JavaScript');
        $this->_put('/JS '.$this->_textstring($this->javascript));
        $this->_put('>>');
        $this->_put('endobj');
    }

    function _putresources() {
        parent::_putresources();
        if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
            $this->_putjavascript();
        }
    }

    function _putcatalog() {
        parent::_putcatalog();
        if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
            $this->_put('/Names <</JavaScript '.($this->n_js).' 0 R>>');
        }
    }
}



class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript
{
    function AutoPrint($printer='')
    {
        // Open the print dialog
        if($printer)
        {
            $printer = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $printer);
            $script = "var pp = getPrintParams();";
            $script .= "pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;";
            $script .= "pp.printerName = '$printer'";
            $script .= "print(pp);";
        }
        else
            $script = 'print(true);';
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
    }
}



$pdf = new PDF_AutoPrint();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 20);
$pdf->Text(90, 50, 'Print me!');
$pdf->AutoPrint();
$pdf->Output();
```

And it works fine, but I need it to combine with this:

```
require('lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');
//require('lib/fpdi-2.0.1/src/autoload.php');
require('lib/fpdi-1.6.1/fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile("BCEB_20171207_100_A_1_51.pdf");

$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 

$pdf->Output();
```

I really have no idea how to combine both (with `autoload` classes aroud fpdi?). Alternative that would help - another way to load ready pdf into fpdf and output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [Print PDF in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254679/print-pdf-in-firefox)

```
<?php


require('lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require('lib/fpdi-1.6.1/fpdi.php');


class PDF_JavaScript extends FPDI {

    var $javascript;
    var $n_js;

    function IncludeJS($script) {
        $this->javascript=$script;
    }

    function _putjavascript() {
        $this->_newobj();
        $this->n_js=$this->n;
        $this->_out('<<');
        $this->_out('/Names [(EmbeddedJS) '.($this->n+1).' 0 R]');
        $this->_out('>>');
        $this->_out('endobj');
        $this->_newobj();
        $this->_out('<<');
        $this->_out('/S /JavaScript');
        $this->_out('/JS '.$this->_textstring($this->javascript));
        $this->_out('>>');
        $this->_out('endobj');
    }

    function _putresources() {
        parent::_putresources();
        if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
            $this->_putjavascript();
        }
    }

    function _putcatalog() {
        parent::_putcatalog();
        if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
            $this->_out('/Names <</JavaScript '.($this->n_js).' 0 R>>');
        }
    }
}

class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript
{
    function AutoPrint($dialog=false)
    {
        //Open the print dialog or start printing immediately on the standard printer
        $param=($dialog ? 'true' : 'false');
        $script="print($param);";
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
    }

    function AutoPrintToPrinter($server, $printer, $dialog=false)
    {
        $script = "document.contentWindow.print();";
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
    }
}

$pdf=new PDF_AutoPrint();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("BCEB_20171207_28_A_1_04_long.pdf");
// $pageCount = $pdf -> setSourceFile("BCEB_20171207_100_A_1_51.pdf");
//Open the print dialog
//$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox'); //this you need to do on every page

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);        
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 
}

$pdf->AutoPrint(true);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: This will create a PDF with the page count of the input file but only the first page will be placed on all pages - I guess a simple bug. Almost a correct answer but please do **NOT use legacy versions**! Please use the latest versions of all invloved classes. The used FPDI version is from 2015. Please update the code to [FPDI 2](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/)!

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that on end of friday that all pages are the same :P To fixt this you need to add `$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);` at the start of the `for`